# Issue with alias in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am facing a problem with `alias` command in bash. I created `.bashrc` in my home directory and added an alias as below:

```
test() { "test_command_$1"; }
alias au=test
```

But when I open a new terminal and try to execute the command through alias like `au arg1` it complains:

```
bash: test_command_arg1: command not found
```

But if I execute aliased command manually in the same terminal as `test_command_arg1` it is working fine. I checked the `PATH` variable and it's fine. Can somebody help me to fix this?

P.S: `test_command_` is just an example. It is not the actual command being tried.

Comment: type `alias` in terminal and see the output..Those are enables aliases

Comment: I have already checked this. I am getting `alias au='test'` in terminal.

Comment: Are you using exactly `test_command_$1`? So it would do `test_command_arg1`? It sounds weird to me.

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://ideone.com/Uxz8tx)

Comment: If you really named your function `test` you could potentially run into trouble since there already exists a command named `test`.

Comment: @Ube: Can you please provide more details about that?

Comment: @Newbie I'd like to cite from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/style#function_names: "A more or less funny one: If not intended to do so, do not name your functions like common commands, typically new users tend to name their scripts or functions test, which collides with the UNIX test command! "

Comment: Let me change the function name and test again.

Comment: @Ube: I tried with the different name, but still it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the "command not found" error because of what your `test()` function does.

```
test() { "test_command_$1"; }
```

When you call this with an argument, `$1` is replaced with that argument (I guess you knew  this bit). So if you call `au arg1`, what your function is trying to do is this:

```
"test_command_arg1"
```

The shell is trying to execute it as a command. `test_command_arg1` isn't a recognised command, so you get an error. Try changing your test function:

```
test() { echo "test_command_$1"; }
```

Comment: To go with this, your `PATH` is probably not configured to look for command names in the current directory. Change the test function to `test () { "./test_command_$1"; }`

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am able to run the same command manually. So it is a valid command.